# Trigger a device orientation change when screen is removed from Navigation stack (ie user goes "Back")

Tags: flutter, device-orientation

This app sets the device orientation to portrait within `main()`:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp],
  ).then((_) {
    runApp(const MyApp());
  });
}
```

One screen is a slideshow, which is set to landscape:

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
  DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
]);
return MaterialApp(
  ...
);
```

The problem is when the user returns from the slideshow to the "Main Screen", the orientation does not switch again. However if the screen is *pushed* onto the Navigation stack, the orientation changes as expected.

#### Current Flow

> - Splash (Portrait)
> - Main Screen (Portrait)
> - Slideshow (Landscape)
> - Main Screen, back from Slideshow (still Landscape) <<- ***this should trigger portrait again!***
> - Splash (still Landscape)
> - Forward to Main Screen <<- now this re-triggers the orientation change

How can the orientation be re-triggered when screens are popped (removed) from the navigation stack?

#### Edit

I should also note, I've tried to add a trigger to the main screen, but this has no effect:

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 3 ways how you can set your orientation back to portrait when you navigate back:

You wrap your landscape widget with a WillPopScope and call setPreferredOrientations inside onWillPop:

```
return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
          [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp],
        );
        return Future.value(true);
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
```

You make your second widget stateful and call setPreferredOrientations in dispose:

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp],
    );
    super.dispose();
  }
```

You await the Navigator.push or Navigator.pushNamed call and do the orientation change after returning back from the second screen:

```
await Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()));
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp],
    );
```

Comment: Perfect, the `WillPopScope` method worked flawlessly!